# jqGrid Column Resize Show Column Dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid for the first time replacing datatables Its resizing column is great but it shows the resized column when we stop dragging. Is it possible to see it resized *while* dragging the mouse?

Here's the fiddle:

jsfiddle.net/98RD3/2/

Right now it only resizes when we stop dragging.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: As long as **jqGrid** is [Open Source](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/tree/master), you can always adapt the code to your needs. I think what you ask **jqGrid** to do is perfectly feasible, but maybe it's not available right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly is the problem which you have. The standard behavior of resizing is thze following:

- on mouse down between columns the resizer will be shown
- moving mouse on left or right you specify new position of the column separator. During the time the mouse button should be down. During the time the resizer will be only shown, but the grid are shown in the original look.
- after the mouse button will be released the resizing will be applied

So probably there are just an misunderstanding what the grid do during resizing.

It's important to understand that jqGrid 4.5.4 have a bug. So the resizer could be shown on the wrong position. The bug and the fix is described in [the pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/529).

Nevertheless the demo which you posted have some small errors or bad usage. The fixed demo you can find here: jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/98RD3/4/.

Comment: @after the mouse button will be released the resizing will be applied.                    yes u r right but I want bit different, it should resize as we drag, is it possible? thanks

Comment: @MajinVegeta: What exactly you want? Do you want that *the whole* grid will be resized during every onmousemove event? It will be very slow and it is not possible in jqGrid.

Comment: no, I just want to resize the column on mousemovement as in the very last example(calendar) of this page. http://www.ita.es/jquery/jquery.kiketable.colsizable.htm this one is resizing the grid as well thats not required. Thanks alot

Comment: @MajinVegeta: The only difference which I see in the demo (if I compare it with jqGrid standard behavior) is that the background color of the resized column will be changed during resizing. So it still "only resizes when we stop dragging" (see the text of your question). You can try to use `resizeStart` and `resizeStop` [callbacks](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events) or jqGrid to do this.

Comment: there is a big difference u didn't notice. check this http://screencast.com/t/bSBhSjKpB it immediately resize the column as u move mouse, it don't show the line as jqgrid shows. thanks

Comment: @MajinVegeta: Now I see the difference. In any way there are no option in jqGrid which woukd change the resizing behavior to what you want. You will have to change [mousemove](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.4/js/grid.base.js#L2844-L2846) event or overwrite `$("#tbl_Grid")[0].grid.dragMove` method and probably `dragStart` and `dragEnd` too (see [the source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.4/js/grid.base.js#L862-L927)).